# Angular2 Working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, typescript, angular

FIREFOX ERRORS:

```
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property G.search es6-shim.min.js:10:7752
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property G[e] es6-shim.min.js:10:1
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create es6-shim.min.js:10:23659
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property S.setImmediate es6-shim.min.js:11:1066
TypeError: variable load redeclares argument system.src.js:685:12
TypeError: variable load redeclares argument system.src.js:741:10
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:1393:64
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:3838:45
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:3841:46
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:3848:47
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:4024:46
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable $__curScript system.src.js:5006:3
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property cfg.transpilerRuntime system.src.js:1870:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property value.then zone.js:502:10
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.format system.src.js:2763:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.authorization system.src.js:1739:7
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata[metaName] system.src.js:4838:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.format system.src.js:1773:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.format system.src.js:3348:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.format system.src.js:3464:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.format system.src.js:4236:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.cjsRequireDetection system.src.js:3877:13
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.esmExports system.src.js:3416:7
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:3:978
TypeError: variable loc redeclares argument browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:3:7667
SyntaxError: 'use strict' statement won't be enforced as a directive because it isn't in directive prologue position browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:10:0
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property freeGlobal.global browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:3:19111
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property has[name] browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:3:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property freeGlobal.global browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:2:21756
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property opts.reconnection browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:2:27861
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property freeGlobal.global browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:1:3315
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property packet.options browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:3:602
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property self.pingIntervalTimer browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:1:9391
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.pingTimeoutTimer browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:1:9135
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property packet.data browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:1:8193
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property cb.fn browser-sync-client.2.12.8.js:2:3388
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property load.metadata.globals system.src.js:3629:16
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property linkSet.loader.loaderObj.execute system.src.js:682:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property freeGlobal.global system.src.js line 1510 > eval:15:1
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? system.src.js:5:79
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property obj.provide system.src.js line 1510 > eval:4:19
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property typeOrFunc.parameters system.src.js line 1510 > eval:117:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property ctorParam.decorators system.src.js line 1510 > eval:124:80
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property typeOrFunc.annotations system.src.js line 1510 > eval:142:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property typeOrFunc.propMetadata system.src.js line 1510 > eval:163:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.requiredParents system.src.js line 1510 > eval:288:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property value["name"] system.src.js line 1510 > eval:377:12
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

TSCONFIG.JSON

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

TYPINGS.JSON

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

SYSTEMJS.CONFIG.JS

```
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];
    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
  </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<checkout-app>Loading...</checkout-app>
</body>
</html>
```

MAIN.TS

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

APP.COMPONENT.TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'checkout-app',
    template: `
<h1>Test</h1>
`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I have searched everywhere and have tried all the fixes I could find but cannot come up with a solution on how to get the errors in FireFox to go away.

Comment: That is a lot of code to share, perhaps placing it in a plunker would be easier?

Comment: All it is is the quickstart from angular.io

Comment: Try putting Reflect.js before es6-shim in index.html. This solved a similar problem for me when Safari was crashing on me. Long shot, but who knows...

Comment: That didn't fix any of the errors.

Comment: I found that FireFox was caching my outdated files. I also had to had this to any post and get headers when trying to retrieve data from a server in JSON becuase the default way FireFox gets data does not work with Angular 2  `headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that FireFox was caching my outdated files. I also had to add this to any post and get headers when trying to retrieve data from a server in JSON becuase the default way FireFox gets data does not work with Angular 2

```
headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');
```