# What is the meaning of q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9 in Header

Tags: angular, http, firefox, xmlhttprequest, http-accept-header

I have this doubt related with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304116/angular2-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox). The solution is to simply included

```
q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9
```

as '**Accept**' in the **Request Header**. But what is the meaning of this expression? I can see that the semicolon is used twice and coma is not used to seperate any different media type as outlined [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4).

When I add this to my code my application works on Firefox but I get a 406 Not-Acceptable error. Is there any possible reason for this ( my return type is JSON). Would appreciate any thoughts on both my doubts.